# How can i check whether the key is present in the node or not?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is the structure. I have a main node and inside are keys.how can I check that a particular key exists inside this node or not ?

```
 let ref = firebase.database().ref(userID);
  ref.orderByKey().equalTo(key).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    document.getElementById('chat_box').style.display = 'none';
    console.log("This ad is posted by you - " + userID) ;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) function that can be called.

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('yourNode/yourKey');

ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.exists());  // true
  }
```

Comment: it is printing on console every time whether that key exists in that node or not

Comment: Yes, it is to demonstrate whether the node exists or not, what is it that you wanted to do with that information?

Comment: i am viewing an ad and have key of that ad which i am currently viewing . if that ad i am currently viewing exists in the main node then dont show me the chat box else show the chat box

Comment: OK, so you can do `if(snapshot.exists()) ` for `node/key` and put your logic after that.